# OpenCL's get_default_queue() always returns 0

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I'm trying to get device-side enqueuing working in my OpenCL application, but no matter what I do, get_default_queue() returns 0.

1. I've set up a second command queue with on device, on device default and out of order exec mode enabled
2. I've checked that the device enqueue capabilities supports device side enqueuing
3. I've checked that the main command queue device default returns the device command queue
4. I've got the CL3.0 compile tag
5. The kernel functions perfectly fine in every way except for this.

My code can be found here: https://github.com/labiraus/svo-tracer/blob/main/SvoTracer/SvoTracer.Kernel/EnqueueTest.cs

A stripped down version of the kernel:

```
    kernel void test(global int *out) {
        int i = get_global_id(0);
        if (get_default_queue() != 0) {
            out[i] = 1;
        } else {
            out[i] = 2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCL 3.0 this became an optional feature. Whilst some devices will correctly return that device side enqueuing is not supported, it seems that the card I was testing on may not support it whilst reporting that it did.

Ultimately device-side enqueuing isn't functionality that can be relied upon to be implemented by OpenCL 3.0 compatible devices.